# One of the definitions of magnetic field which is given by using nabla operators

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vector-fields, calculus, magnetic-moment

$$  \boldsymbol{M}:=\text{magnetic moment vector}  $$

$$  \boldsymbol{H} := \text{magnetic field vector which is generated at }~ \boldsymbol{r} ~ \text{by} ~  \boldsymbol{M} ~ $$

$$ \boldsymbol{r}:=\text{displacement vector which is composed of }~r~\text{and}~\theta~$$

$$  \phi_{m}:=\frac{  \boldsymbol{M} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}  }{  4\pi\mu_{0}  r ^{3}   }  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{magnetic scalar potential}  $$

$$  \boldsymbol{H}:= - \nabla \phi_{m}  $$

$$ = - \nabla \left( \frac{  \boldsymbol{M}  \cdot \boldsymbol{r} }{ 4\pi\mu_{0} r ^{3}    }  \right)  $$

$$ = - \frac{  1  }{  4\pi\mu_{0}   } \nabla \left( \frac{  \boldsymbol{M}\cdot  \boldsymbol{r}  }{  r ^{3}   }  \right)　 \tag{1} $$

$$ = -\frac{  1  }{  4\pi\mu_{0}   }  \left\{ \left( \boldsymbol{M}\cdot  \boldsymbol{r} \right) \nabla \left( \frac{  1  }{  r ^{3}   }  \right) + \frac{  1  }{  r ^{3}   } \nabla \left( \boldsymbol{M}\cdot  \boldsymbol{r} \right)   \right\}  \tag{2}$$

$$ = -\frac{  1  }{  4\pi\mu_{0}   }  \left\{ \left( \boldsymbol{M}\cdot  \boldsymbol{r} \right)  \left( -\frac{  3  }{  r ^{4}   } \frac{  \boldsymbol{r}  }{ r   }   \right) + \frac{  1  }{  r ^{3}   } \boldsymbol{M}   \right\} \tag{3} $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{4\pi\mu_{0}} \left\{ -\frac{  \boldsymbol{M}  }{ r ^{3}    } + \frac{  3 \left( \boldsymbol{M} \cdot \boldsymbol{r} \right) \boldsymbol{r}  }{  r ^{5}   }  \right\}  \tag{4} $$

About the first tag, I can easily get that the constant can be got out from the argument of nabla operator.

About the second tag, I can get that the operation similar to $~ \left( f(x)g(x) \right)'=f(x)'g(x)+ f(x)g(x)'   ~$  is done .

About the third tag, what are going on.

First things to first,

$$  \nabla\left( \frac{  1  }{  r ^{3}   }  \right) = -\frac{   3 }{  r ^{4}   } \frac{  \boldsymbol{r}  }{  r  }  $$

Why the right term can gained from the left term?

Second thing is

$$  \nabla\left( \boldsymbol{M}\cdot\boldsymbol{r_{}}  \right) = \boldsymbol{M} $$

Which website(s) should I refer?

**Added.**
$~ 1/r ^{3}  ~$  is not a bold form but of course it can be assumed that $~ 1 / r ^{3}  ~$ has a direction.

So,

$$  \nabla\left( 1/r ^{3}  \right)  $$

$$ = -\frac{  3  }{  r ^{4}   } \cdot \frac{  \boldsymbol{r}  }{  r  }  +0  $$

About the left term is the form of differentiated by the scalar $~r~$ and the right term is the form of differentiated by the direction.

About the right fraction of the left term,

I can guess that this fraction represents the unit vector with some direction.

But why the differentiation of direction? is to be zero?

ps. I will back after about 10 hours.

Comment: Have you tried evaluating that $\nabla(1/r^3)$ componentwise?

Comment: $1/r^3$ is a scalar and does not have a direction, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question, I agree with J. Murray's comment that you should try evaluating the gradient component-wise.

For example for the $x$ component you'll have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right) = \frac{-3}{r^4}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{-3}{r^4}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}
\\
= \frac{-3}{r^4}\frac{x}{r}$$
if you do this for all components you'll get the expression you need.

Regarding your second point, I think $\mathbf{M}$ is constant, in which case $$\nabla (\mathbf{M}\cdot\mathbf{r}) = \nabla (M_1x + M_2 y + M_3 z) = \mathbf{M}$$

Comment: Sorry, your formulas are too difficult for me currently..

Comment: Do you understand what the nabla operator is and what derivatives are? Maybe you should start by asking a question (or friends/teachers) about multidimensional calculus/derivatives.